# JPA/Hibernate SequenceGeneator customization

Tags: hibernate, jpa

This is a question about customize Hibernate SequenceGenerator.

I have an application (Spring 3.1/Hibernate 4) that has to work with two legacy database of Oracle and SQLServer.  I run into issue with  Id generator.

In my Entity, I annotated ID generator strategy as AUTO so that when it works with Oracle, it by default picks up SequenceGenerator and when works with SQLServer it picks up IdentityGenerator by default.  It works with SQLServer with no problem.  But for Oracle, hibernate use hardcoded "hibernate_sequence" as default sequence name. This caused problem because the legacy Oracle database use convention TableName+"_SEQ" as sequence name per table.

I managed to solve the issue by changing  Hibernate SequenceGenerator source code and build my own hibernate code base. But this is less preferable as we have to remember this while upgrading Hibernate.

I also tried to write my own ID Generator (and annotated the ID field with it) that switch between SequenceGenerator/IDGenerator but failed. In any case, this is not preferable way either as this will need further dive into inside JPA/Hibernate framework which I am hesitated to do.

What I would like is to write my CustomizedSequenceGenerator and somehow override the one Hibernate is using via configuration.  But I could find the "somehow".

Does anyone has such experience?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom generator by implementing `IdentifierGenerator` interface & then overriding it's `generate` method.

Then you can use it in the entity for generating id.

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="TABLE_X_SEQ", strategy="com.package.TableXIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator="TABLE_X_SEQ")
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back a bit late.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution only works for Oracle. I need it work for SQLServer as well. Both are legacy database that I can't change their schema.  Basically I am looking for the solution that the same Jave code with Entity annotation work for both database - ideally the framework will pick up existing IdentityGenerator for SQLServer and the customized SeqenceGenerator for Oracle.  But I can't replace the existing SequenceGenerator with my customized one. I ended up having to modify existing Hibernate SequenceGenerator directly and build my own Hibernate jar files which is less preferrable.

Comment: @user902650 Glad you found a workaround. Here you have custom generator which will be called regardless of the database, there you can generate key based on the current database. Why are you using strategy as AUTO instead of mentioned above.